# How does re-installing an operating system on a primary drive impact data on mounted filesystems?

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, mount, operating-systems

I have a machine with 3 separate SSD drives:

- `sda` - Holds the operating system itself (Ubuntu)
- `sdb` - Personal Data
- `sdc` - Personal Data

`sdb` and `sdbc` are mounted drives.

Say I planned on wiping the OS from `sda` and installing a new operating system. I'd then (re-)mount the 2 data drives:

1. Would my files still be readable?
2. Would my files still have the same permissions / owners (assuming those users exist on my new OS user space)?
3. Would it matter if I installed Ubuntu or switched to a totally different distro like Arch?

Thanks!

Comment: Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment. Home and end-user computing questions may be asked on Super User

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope this question will be migrated, but it doesn't belongs to Server Fault. Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment. Home and end-user computing questions may be asked on Super User.

1. Yes. Just make sure you wipe/install your OS on correct drive.
2. Yes. But note that Linux filesystems store permissions as numbers (UID/GID), not as names. That means that your new users and groups should also match their IDs. You can obtain those on current OS by reading `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` files.
3. It won't matter as long as you are reinstalling from scratch.

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate you answering the question even though it's in the wrong forum. I will migrate it to SuperUser